# how to create an external javascript file for tracking a user and alerting the data

Tags: javascript, geoip

I am using this code in html page, but i need a seperate javascript file that should alert data.

Actually a variable should be created in html file and is sent to the .js file which alerts the data

But i cannot be able to store the city name in a variable.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>home</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//j.maxmind.com/js/apis/geoip2/v2.0/geoip2.js"></script>

        <script>
            geoip2.cityISPOrg(function (response) {
                $("#country").html(response.country.names.en);
            }, null, { w3cGeolocationDisabled: true });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            <span id="country"></span>,
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I changed the above code to two seperate files, one of which is html file and the other is .js file

html file calls the js file and the code in the .js file is

```
var country;
$(window).load(function(){
geoip2.cityISPOrg(function (response) {
country = $("#country").html(response.country.names.en);
}, null, { w3cGeolocationDisabled: true });
alert(country);
});
```

its alerting undefined and its not alerting the country value and i think country value is not storing in the variable.
Can anyone tell me how to store the value in the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this ?

```
alert($("#country").html());
```